# Is there any way to make each class that implements interface Ae has a List of one of the concrete classes that implement Ba as property?

Tags: c#, implements, concreteclass, interface-class

- I have an interface (Ae) that has a list of objects (List) from another interface (Ba).
- I have a class that implements interface Ae.
- I have several classes that implement the Ba interface.

Is there any way to make each class that implements interface Ae has a List of one of the concrete classes that implement Ba as property?

```
public interface IQuestion
{
    IAnswerOption[] Answers { get; set; }
}

public interface IAnswerOption
{
    int Id { get; }
    bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerOptionText : IAnswerOption
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public bool isCorrect;
    public string ansText;
}

public class AnswerOptionImage : IAnswerOption
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public bool isCorrect;
    public string imgSlug;
}

public class AudioQuestion : IQuestion
{
    public AnswerOptionImage[] Answers;
    public string audioName;
}

public class TextQuestion : IQuestion
{
    public AnswerOptionText[] Answers { get; set; }
    public string questionText { get; set; }
}
```

When I try it, **AudioQuestion** and **TextQuestion** doesn't allow me to use **AnswerOptionImage[]** and **AnswerOptionText[]** respectively.

Visual Studio says that I need to implement interface member IQuestion.Answers, but this is not what I intend.

*If someone can help me I would be very grateful. Thanks.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) for your `IQuestion` interface will be a good fit:

```
public interface IQuestion<T> where T: IAnswerOption
{
    T[] Answers { get; set; }
}

public class AudioQuestion : IQuestion<AnswerOptionImage>
{
    public AnswerOptionImage[] Answers{ get; set; }
    public string audioName;
}

public class TextQuestion : IQuestion<AnswerOptionText>
{
    public AnswerOptionText[] Answers { get; set; }
    public string questionText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Imagine that in the future I want that class TextQuestion receives both AnswerOptionText[] and AnswerOptionImage[]. 
What would be the best approach to do this? What do you suggest?

Comment: @DiogoFerreira since there is no build in discriminated unions in C# ATM you can try implement some kind of `OneOf<T1, T2>` type (multiple of them with different number of parameters) or use your current one allowing any answer type.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by OneOf<T1,T2> (where can I see more about it?). 
How can I use my current one allowing any answer type? This is enough public class TextQuestion : IQuestion<IAnswerOption>? Sorry for the questions but I am a beginner and it is all so confusing for me.